# c++ how to use while properly

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am learning c++ around two weeks and therefore have a lot of questions. It feels like i learn a new sport. My body in my thinking already moving much better than any other olympic players, but the actual movement is so poor.

what i want to know is if i can use "while" in cout together.

```
int main() {
struct {
    string engineType;
    string brand;
    int price;
    int range;
} candidate1, candidate2;

// information of candidate 1
candidate1.name = "IONIQ5";
candidate1.range = 450;
candidate1.price = 35000;

// information of candidate 2
candidate2.brand = "Tesla_Model_3";
candidate2.range = 650;
candidate2.price = 55000;

// show each price with while function
int i = 1;
while (i<3) {
    cout << "Price :" << candidate[i].range << endl ;
    i++;
}
return 0;
```

I want to have as a result of print

```
450
650
```

what do i have to do to get it ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Unrelated: `while` is not a function.

Comment: You can create an array and then loop through it and print the value.

Comment: you have to learn how to create an array of structs, just google it you will get many answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array with elements of type `Candidate` and then loop through the array and print the values as shown below:

```
//class representing a Candidate info
struct Candidate{
    string engineType;
    string brand;
    int price;
    int range;
};


int main() {

    //create an array witht element of type Candidate;
    Candidate arr[] = {{"IONIQ5", "Honda", 450, 3500}, {"Tesla_Model_3", "Tesla", 650, 55000}};
    
    //iterate through the array using range based for loop 
    for(const Candidate& candidate: arr)
    {
        std::cout<<candidate.range<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/m6LXWdLIr)

Answer (score 3):

Use an *array* and initialize it.

First you need to name your structure:

```
struct candidate {
    std::string engineType;
    std::string brand;
    int price;
    int range;
};
```

Then create and initialize the array:

```
std::array<candidate, 2> candidates = {
    { "Electric", "IONIQ5", 35000, 450 },
    { "Electric", "Tesla_Model_3", 55000, 650 }
};
```

And finally iterate over it:

```
for (auto const& candidate : candidates) {
    std::cout << "Price: " << candidate.price << '\n';
}
```

All this should be well-covered in [a decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: Wouldn't it be more conventional to make class names lowercase? As a reserved convention for concepts.

Comment: @StackDanny To be honest capitalizing class and structure names isn't my personal style, but it's common for beginners in C++. But it is, after all, just a matter of personal style and preference.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use candidate1 like candidate[i] because it works as a variable name . You need to use maps or arrays for this type of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring 2 separate variables, called candidate1 and candidate2 as an array, so candidate[i] does not resolve to anything.

You need to initialize the array as follows:

```
main ()
{
  struct 
  {
    string engineType;
    string brand;
    int price;
    int range;
  } candidate[3];

    
// information of candidate 1
  candidate[1].brand = "IONIQ5";
  candidate[1].range = 450;
  candidate[1].price = 35000;

// information of candidate 2
  candidate[2].brand = "Tesla_Model_3";
  candidate[2].range = 650;
  candidate[2].price = 55000;

// show each price with while function
  int i = 1;
  while (i < 3)
    {
      cout << "Price :" << candidate[i].range << endl;
      i++;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Please note that arrays start with 0, so an array of 3 will have values for postitions 0, 1, 2, hence the candidate[3], but I would recommend going with candidate[2] and setting values for positions 0 and 1.

Comment: btw, I would recommend you check this tutorial out, it's good and takes you step by step https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm

Comment: To mee, this looks much more like C than C++

Comment: it's the OPs code with only a few lines changed, and it's c++

Comment: hi, Urwald,
can you tell me why you feel this code is like C rather than C++ ?